# Employee asking experience letter from the date of internship to last day of working as employee , management is ok can i give false date?

Tags: human-resources

below is the situation

A candidate was taken as intern for 6 months after which job offer was given , now after 2.5 years the candidate has quit and asking for experience letter from the date of internship , the management is totally ok to give the letter with false date of employment. What is the consequences for both parties and how should i do the documentation as management is asking me do it inspite of me stating its wrong . please help with suggestion.

Comment: Can you please add a bit more info. How incorrect is the false date? Are we talking about a few days?

Comment: internship period - 2.1.2020 - 1.05.2020 employment date- 02.05.2020-31.08.2023 candidate asking exp letter 2.1.2020-31.08.2023

Comment: Location is very important here.  In the US it would not be considered a false date nor do company's typically provide such a letter.  From the other side it would be acceptable for this person to claim that he worked at this company for 3 years.

Comment: What is your authority? Are you the signatory? Or are you simply suppose to type the letter and take a printed/electronic copy for signature from someone else? or, are you someone just overhearing a conversation?

Comment: Looks like your issue is that you don't consider internship as employment. I certainly do. That is a defensible position, and thus no problem.

Answer (score 12):

In most countries internships (even unpaid ones) ARE a form of employment (for tax, legal and insurance purposes) so I don't see anything "false" here.

A reference letter should state the total time of employment (2.1.2020-31.08.2023) and the job title for each role that had during their employment. Something like

- Jan 2020 - Marc 2020: intern in XYZ department
- April 2020 - Dec 2022: junior junior QA tester
- Jan 2023 - August 2023: software developer

> can i give experience letter including the internship period ,as the date of joining on payslips will differ from the date i mention in the experience letter

You need to check your local labor laws and what paperwork was in place during the internship. As I said: internship is typically considered a form of employment.

Comment: thank you for taking your time in suggesting ill take this into consideration .

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the Candidate has said they had 3 years experience as that's generally one of the thresholds of experience (1 year, 3 years, 5 years, 10+)

In which case, given the circumstances (Intern at the same company, then worked there for 2.5 years) - I'd be fine with it too. I don't think this is falsifying information.

As for consequences? I mean obviously such an egregious offence would be met with the death penalty...

I jest. No one will care. As above, I don't even consider it to be falsifying anything - he worked continuously at a role, in the same company for 3 years.

Comment: internship period - 2.1.2020 - 1.05.2020
employment date- 02.05.2023-31.08.2023
candidate asking exp letter 2.1.2020-31.08.2023

Comment: can i give experience letter  including the internship period ,as the date of joining on payslips will differ from the date i mention in the experience letter.

Comment: They were continously employed. I'm fully on the candidates and Management side here.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to reply for my query &  guiding me through

Comment: I disagree a little,  While they did work for that company, the positions were different, and a reference letter should spell that out.  It might come out anyway if a prospective employer calls you and asks about it.

Comment: @RohitGupta It doesn't matter if the "positions" are a little different. The letter says the date of employment.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly is it a false information?

Internship is same as work, just benefit of free labor to employer.

As i see it the person worked for the company for 3 years